# Magnetic field due to sheet current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image: Sheet]

Suppose we have current flowing along very long thin sheet with current per unit length as $\lambda$ so what would would be magnetic field at distance $r$ from this sheet?

Using Ampere Law $$\int_C^{}\vec{B}.\vec{dl}=\mu_0.I_{enclosed}$$
I did $$\vec{B}.2\pi R=\mu_0.\lambda.2R$$
giving us $B$ as $$B=\frac{\mu_0.\lambda}{\pi}$$
is this result correct??

Comment: In a word, no. You need to think a little bit more carefully about the symmetry in the problem. This will most likely get closed as it is a homework question. Try and rephrase it such that it complies with the sites guidance on homework questions. http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Field are also circular , why is this wrong ?

Comment: I am assuming the currents are the purple dots and moving into or out of the screen?

Comment: Yes they are like that

Comment: Consider adding the magnetic field from each current pairwise i.e. the one at the left end and the one at the right end together and work towards the centre. You might be able to spot the resultant field which will give you a clue as to what sort of shape you should pick for your amperian loop.

Comment: Generally you should also try to do some research yourself before asking here. Searching the words "current sheet" into google would provide many helpful links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not correct because your Amperian loop is wrong.The circle has a more difficult integral.You can not get B out of the integral in a circular Amperian loop because in each point there is a different angle between B and dl,so the dot product between them changes.
By saying that it is a long thin sheet i assume that it has infinite dimensions and zero thickness.Also,i suppose that the current has direction coming out of the screen.
Having said that,we can say that the magnetic field for a current that is flowing outside the screen is looking to the left for the upper half(from sheet and up) and looking to the right for the lower part(from the sheet and down).It homogeneous for each part.
So the Amperian loop that you must take is a square because the upper and lower sides will have a B that gets out of the integral while the left and right sides will give an integral equal to zero.
The enclosed current is also easy to calculate.

Comment: You generally shouldn't give answers to questions like this straight away. The person asking the question learns a lot more by working through the problem.

Comment: I person like me would try to solve this and if i failed then i would change my way of thinking until i found the mistake.This develops intuition.But if a person asks the community for an answer,i must assume that this person has done its best to find the answer and did not accomplished its goal.I am not here to tell somebody to go back to the drawing board.I am here to help.If that person did not do its best to find the correct solution,then it is on them.They will not develop intuition and they are fooling themselves.I can only hope that they really tried!So,in s way,i agree with you!

Comment: The hardest part which i have not given the answer to,is WHY the magnetic field point that way?That needs intuition and smart thinking!So,he can give himself that answer ;)